# Android kernel 'fstack-protector-strong not supported` error

Tags: 14.04, command-line, kernel, compiling, gcc

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I have GCC 4.9 installed on my machine.
I am trying to compile the Android kernel and I'm getting the below error,

```
Makefile:660: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 1
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

Any way that I could solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the MakeFile in the kernel/rpi directory we're working in.
See: "**Makefile:660:** Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler"

Go to line 660 and comment out the block of code relating to CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG then try again :)

Comment: gcc 4.9 does supports -fstack-protector-strong per documentation hence I expect this to work!, anyone faced similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have melt this problem.
As to the output `Makefile:660: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong  not supported by compiler`,the compiler doesn't support -fstack-protector-strong.

When compiling the Android Kernel,the `CROSS_COMPILE` env sets the gcc toolchains we used.So you  can set the env to AOSP gcc toolchain position or you can download new toolchains and set the env to it.

For example:

```
# install toolchain,default in /usr/bin
sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu gcc-arm-linux-gnueab
export CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-
```

or

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android-
export PATH=~/data/AOSP/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin:$PATH
```